# Generators with EV motors

Tags: batteries, ac, dc-motor, motor-controller, generator

I've read several questions/responses about AC generator(s) running EV motors, but they are all talking about gas or diesel-powered generators.

My question is along similar lines.

My idea is a PTO-driven generator(s) being driven by the torque from the front tires/rims via CV input shafts, like a front-wheel-drive car, turning the PTO generator(s).

The concept is basically the same in that the generator(s) would supply AC power to the controller for the motor. The RPM of the tires would be regulated by a gear reduction drive to take the RPM down from the thousands to hundreds that PTO generators can use.

I've thought about friction loss, parasitic drag, etc. from the various components, but my mind says it's still possible.

I'm not saying this would run a car/truck for 1000 miles or more, but if it could complement a daily drive of 300 to 400 miles to 500 or more miles wouldn't it be worth it?

---

Yes, I felt that it kind of represented a PMM, but here's a bit more detail after reading the comments.

The batteries would initially power the motor (wheels) until the PTO generator(s) get to their proper output and then the automatic transfer switch would switch over from the batteries to the generator. Now, that being said the battery bank would still eventually need to be charged like all EV's by an external source, due to supplying the initial start up power for the motor at low speeds.

Now since the batteries would not be used to run the motor at high speeds or  continuously the battery bank should last quite a bit longer (i.e. part of the longer distance.) The transfer switch would switch the power back and forth between the battery bank (low speeds) and the generator (high speeds) as needed. So, not a PMM in the sense!

The attached pic was done on my phone since the more detailed one is at work, so keep laughing to a dull roar please! The battery bank feeds the motor thru the transfer switch. The generator feeds the motor thru the transfer switch as well. The switch decides which power input takes president based on the load demand. Kind of like a backup generator at a house, when the power drops or goes off. Neither the battery bank nor the generator feed each other at any time.

[image]

---

I know there is parasitic loss and friction loss as well, but what I am trying to figure out is if this is even possible. Maybe a small scale first, then large scale afterwards?

Comment: It sounds like you think you've invented a self-charging hybrid. What's powering your wheels?

Comment: What would this generator supply? I mean why do you need it. What motor will power this generator? As you said "but they are all talking about gas or diesel-powered generators", so what are you talking about, how it should be powered?

Comment: Seems like a perpetual motion machine. Basically, what you’re proposing is what regeneration does. Unlike what you’re proposing, regeneration only comes into play during braking when you’re trying to shed kinetic energy. If you’re using energy to move the vehicle at at the same time, it makes no sense, even if you’re recovering that energy: the losses will eat you alive.

Comment: Draw a diagram of your system showing all the energy sources, conversions and sinks.

Comment: _"So, not a PMM "_ - Yes, it is. [There ain't no such thing as a free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch)

Comment: Of course there is no such thing as a PMM, we all know that. I by no means even suggest this is or even close.

Comment: @StevenRobinson You think you're not suggesting it, but you still are because your idea is based on the same misconception that PMMs are.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how one would do the calculations with some numbers picked out of the air but close enough to reality:

- Efficiency of motor: 90%. The rest goes as heat.
- Efficiency of generator: 85%. The rest goes as mechanical losses.
- Generator output power: 20 kW.

---

- Generator input power = \$ \frac {output\ power}{efficiency} = \frac {20}{0.85} = 23.5 \ \text {kW}\$.
- Power required by motor to deliver 23.5 kW to the generator = \$ \frac {output\ power} {efficiency} = \frac {23.5} {0.90} = 26.1 \ \text {kW}\$.
- Result: You need to supply 26.1 kW to generate 20 kW so you have lost 6.1 kW and gained nothing.

If this is not what you are asking then please clarify in your question and show some calculations.

Comment: Right on target! These are numbers that I am needing. Thank you! I know it's difficult to understand what I am doing, but I just need a bit of help on the calculations and numbers and I will eventually post the prototype in small scale and then go from there.

Comment: *"I know it's difficult to understand what I am doing ...*" Only because you haven't explained it at all well. Can you edit your question to clarify? Are you sure that you understand that my numbers are telling you that your scheme will **cost** energy, not generate it?

Answer (score 2):

> My idea is a PTO-driven generator(s) being driven by the torque from the front tires/rims via CV input shafts, like a front-wheel-drive car, turning the PTO generator(s).
>
> The concept is basically the same in that the generator(s) would supply AC power to the controller for the motor.

Okay, so your idea is to use a [power takeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_take-off) device to take mechanical power from the axle, convert it into electric power, and feed electric power back into the motor.

How much power will your system deliver to the motor? Will it give the motor less power, the same amount of power, or more power than it takes from the axle?

If your system delivers less power to the motor than it takes from the axle, then your system isn't very useful, because the motor will have to consume extra power from the battery in order to maintain the speed of the car. It'll make the car less efficient, not more efficient.

If your system delivers more power to the motor than it takes from the axle, then that extra power has to come from somewhere, like a fuel tank or another battery. (No system can output an unlimited amount of energy.) So your system still isn't very useful.

And if your system delivers the same amount of power to the motor that it takes from the axle, then it won't hurt anything, but it won't help anything, either.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. What size PTO generator(s) would be needed is just one part of the equation! I am working on determining the amount of torque the front tires are capable of producing at various speeds to be able to write the correct algorithm for the system to use when deciding the transfer switch times/rates, etc. The RPM of the front tires/CV shafts is easy to determine various speeds, it's more the torque being the issue. Weight of the front end to maintain proper ground contact to get maximum torque vs. the amount of overall weight of the vehicle (small vehicle for testing purposes)

Comment: Agreed on the unlimited amount of energy. This idea is only to extend the distance of the vehicle not provide unlimited energy. Believe it or not, you are all helping me in my design and numbers. Please don't give up on me yet guys!

Comment: @StevenRobinson Well, my point is that generators and motors aren't going to extend the distance of the vehicle at all. There are only two ways to extend the range of a vehicle: load it up with more energy to begin with, or decrease the amount of energy it spends in order to move. And the only way to decrease the amount of energy it spends is to identify one of the processes that consumes energy, and make it so that that process consumes less energy. If your invention doesn't do that, then it won't work—it won't extend the distance of the vehicle, not even slightly.

Comment: @StevenRobinson In any case, it sounds like you're having fun with this idea and you're learning a lot, too. So, by all means, keep at it!

Answer (score 1):

**Energy Recovery Is Likely Close to Optimum for Current Technology**

For the hybrid or pure electric vehicle (EV) during regenerative braking the motor/generator already operates in generator mode to recharge the battery. The increase in fuel economy comes from the recovery of kinetic energy back into chemical potential energy during regenerative braking.

How does regenerative braking work?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0b2i5ufN7k0

Hybrid and EV Regenerative Braking:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dC_Qvs_scT0

Optimal Regenerative Braking:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qvf35ANNC3M

**Work, Energy, and Heat**

When we imagine a block sliding down an ideal incline plane (with no friction or heat loss) the initial potential energy is given by PE = mgh (mass times gravitational constant times height in a reference frame). If the block slides down the ideal plane and onto a horizontal surface in the absence of wind resistance then all energy converts to kinetic energy and the block will move at constant speed in perpetuity on the ideal horizontal surface. However due to friction and wind resistance a real block will have reduced kinetic energy at the end of the ramp and the block will come to a stop on a horizontal surface when all remaining energy has been converted to heat which is dissipated to the surroundings.

Imagine using the energy stored in a fuel tank and/or battery of a vehicle to perform work in a cycle. First drive or lift the vehicle to the top of an incline plane. Then coast the vehicle down the plane until it rolls to a stop. Repeat this cycle until there is no more available energy in the fuel tank and/or battery and note the acceleration performance and range of travel for the fuel cycle.

Now imagine the vehicle must drive or lift itself to this starting energy state by discharging the battery through a motor with a hoist or just driving up the ramp. Due to heat loss the decrease of chemical potential energy from the battery will be greater than the increase of gravitational potential energy stored in the vehicle due to its position in the gravitational field.

Now imagine rolling the vehicle down the ramp with energy recovery to the battery via standard recovery generation or the proposed power take-off. The effort to recover chemical potential energy in to the battery will reduce the acceleration and top speed of the vehicle compared to rolling the vehicle down the plane without any effort (work performed) to charge the battery. The energy stored in the battery via this process will be less than the initial gravitational potential energy due to heat loss in the electrical and mechanical systems.

The potential energy stored in the battery is equivalent to gravitational potential energy for efforts to accelerate the vehicle up to speed. Regenerative braking only reduces acceleration available from the energy source when appropriate to driving conditions and would not extend the range of the vehicle without reducing its performance.

Since the existing motors are also used as generators to recover energy when appropriate to the driving conditions the addition of another power take-off would likely only reduce energy efficiency and performance of the vehicle with less driving range rather than an extended driving range.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that having the generator just consumes MORE power than not having it there right? If the generator is connected while the motor is running the motor pulls extra battery power to turn the generator.

If the generator is only connected when the motor is disconnected (coasting) the car slows down faster than if the generator were not there because the generator is removing kinetic energy from the car.

Either way, you're just taking power out of the battery in one way or another and running it uselessly in a roundabout fashion all the while incurring losses.

There's no point constantly constantly accelerating and decelerating and incurring extra losses from the generator inefficiency in the process when you could just maintain just enough power to over come frictional losses and maintain speed.

What you've come up with is a system that uses the generator inefficiency as a brake for the car to bleed power from the car. Unlike a regular brake, it is not as effective. Unlike regen braking it is not storing energy and is even less effective than regen braking because instead of removing the kinetic energy and storing it the battery, it tries to cycle as much of it back to the motor and wheels.

Comment: Understood. The generator(s) would be powered by the front tires via a gear reduction box. The motor would only be run by the batteries until the PTO generators reach the proper power output. I'm looking at what to use to handle or store the AC power put out by the generator(s) to be used by the motor.

Comment: @StevenRobinson You still don't get it. Where do you think the power to turn the front tires comes from in the first place? It *will not* extend the range unless you only use it when you are braking or going down hill. And in both those cases there is no such thing as "the motor will only be run by the batteries until the PTO generator reaches proper output". You saying that means you're still thinking perpetual motion machine.